# Strip the time part from data and calculate time difference between consecutive rows using R

Tags: r, date, time, diff

I have an excel file which has a column 'Time' which represents the time. The data type of this column is POSIXct. When I load the excel file in R, some random date part gets appended to the time and so I want to delete this random dates appended, retain only the time part and then calculate the difference between consecutive rows based on grouping Emp_Id and Date columns where I need to see how much was the difference in the clock in and clock out time each day for each employee.

This is how my data looks like when loaded in R with random date getting added.

```
| Emp_Id |    Date   |                 Time | Time_Event |
|--------|:---------:|---------------------:|------------|
| 95     | 3/14/2019 | 1899-12-31 10:47:12  | Clock-In   |
| 95     | 3/12/2019 | 1899-12-31 10:51:12  | Clock-In   |
| 95     | 3/11/2019 | 1899-12-31 8:15:16   | Clock-Out  |
| 95     | 3/12/2019 | 1899-12-31 8:10:07   | Clock-Out  |
| 95     | 3/11/2019 | 1899-12-31 10:41:51  | Clock-In   |
| 19     | 3/14/2019 | 1899-12-31 6:02:23   | Clock-Out  |
| 19     | 3/18/2019 | 1899-12-31 5:44:23   | Clock-In   |
| 19     | 3/12/2019 | 1899-12-31 6:05:15   | Clock-Out  |
| 19     | 3/12/2019 | 1899-12-31 5:45:57   | Clock-In   |
| 19     | 3/14/2019 | 1899-12-31 5:29:32   | Clock-In   |
```

To make it easy, the data will be:

```
Emp_Id <- as.numeric(c("95", "95", "95", "95", "95", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19"))
Date <- c("3/14/2019","3/12/2019","3/11/2019", "3/12/2019","3/11/2019","3/14/2019","3/18/2019","3/12/2019","3/12/2019","3/14/2019")
Time <- as.POSIXct(c("1899-12-31 10:47:12", "1899-12-31 10:51:12", "1899-12-31 8:15:16","1899-12-31 8:10:07", "1899-12-31 10:41:51",
"1899-12-31 6:02:23", "1899-12-31 5:44:23", "1899-12-31 6:05:15", "1899-12-31 5:45:57","1899-12-31 5:29:32"))
Time_Event <- c("Clock-In","Clock-In","Clock-Out","Clock-Out","Clock-In","Clock-Out","Clock-In","Clock-Out","Clock-In","Clock-In")
df2 <- data.frame(Emp_Id,Date,Time,Time_Event, stringsAsFactors = F)
df2$Date= as.Date(df2$Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Using `df$Time <- format(strptime(df$Time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), "%H:%M:%S")` strips the time part but converts the data type to character. Since I need to calculate the difference, I cannot do this on character data type. I have been through this link [How to calculate time difference in consecutive rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49003378/how-to-calculate-time-difference-in-consecutive-rows), but this doesn't help.

I have tried the below code but I get error because of the character data type

```
df2 <- df2 %>%
  arrange(df2$Emp_Id, df2$Date, df2$Time) %>% 
  group_by(df2$Emp_Id,df2$Date) %>%
  mutate(diff = format(strptime(df2$Time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),"%H:%M:%S")- 
           lag(format(strptime(df2$Time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),"%H:%M:%S"),
               default = format(strptime(df2$Time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),"%H:%M:%S")[1]),
         diff_secs = as.numeric(diff, units = 'secs'))
```

How can I achieve the final output to look like:

```
| Emp_Id |    Date   |     Time | Time_Event | Diff(In seconds) |
|--------|:---------:|---------:|------------|------------------|
| 19     | 3/12/2019 |  5:45:57 | Clock-In   | NA               |
| 19     | 3/12/2019 | 18:05:15 | Clock-Out  | 44358            |
| 19     | 3/14/2019 |  5:29:32 | Clock-In   | NA               |
| 19     | 3/14/2019 | 18:02:23 | Clock-Out  | 45171            |
| 19     | 3/18/2019 | 17:44:23 | Clock-In   | NA               |
| 95     | 3/11/2019 | 10:41:51 | Clock-In   | NA               |
| 95     | 3/11/2019 | 20:15:16 | Clock-Out  | 33844            |
| 95     | 3/12/2019 | 10:51:12 | Clock-In   | NA               |
| 95     | 3/12/2019 | 20:10:07 | Clock-Out  | 33535            |
| 95     | 3/14/2019 | 10:47:12 | Clock-In   | NA               |
```

Comment: FYI: Base R does not have a standalone time class only a date/time class, thus R is adding a date to the time.  The date "1899-12-31" is origin of the time keeping system used by Excel.  Since the date is constant, using `difftime` between rows will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df2 %>%
    arrange(Emp_Id, Date, Time) %>%
    group_by(Emp_Id, Date) %>%
    mutate(Diff = as.numeric(Time - lag(Time), units = "secs")) %>%
    ungroup()
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[order(Emp_Id, Date, Time), Date :=
             as.numeric(Time - shift(Time)), .(Emp_Id, Date)]
```